# Make a container moveable in xpages

Tags: dojo, xpages

I'm using Domino 8.5.3 (Dojo 1.5.1),a nd I'm a total beginner regarding Xpages or Dojo.

How can I make a container movable with dojo in 8.5.3?

This is the source of my Xpage. What do I have to add so I can drag and drop 'dndOne' ? Is it even possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoTheme="true">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.dnd.Moveable"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:panel id="dndOne"
        style="width:100px;
            height:100px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            background-color:red">
        I want to move!
        </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks !
François

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/10/dojo-drag-and-drop-1/ for an example.
`<xp:panel>` will end up as `<div>` element in browser.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I have been able to make <div> moveable. I can use a panel as container, but I can't move panels themselves, because the class "dojoDndItem" is not defined for <xp:panel>. Do you know how I solve this ?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I found how to do it. This panel can be moved : <xp:panel><xp:this.attrs><xp:attr name="class" value="dojoDndItem"></xp:attr></xp:this.attrs></xp:panel>